# SATA / SAS Conversion

Tags: sata, compatibility, sas

I was wondering if it is possible to do the following:

1. Connect a motherboard's SATA ports to a SFF-8087 SAS interface
2. Connect the above cable to a internal SFF-8087 to external SFF-8088 adapter
3. Connect this SFF-8088 adapter to an external SAS enclosure that has internal SATA 3 drive connectors but an external SFF-8088 adapter

The goal of doing this is to:

Place all system drives in an external enclosure with no requirement to be able to boot from a drive in the external enclosure (though it is considered a bonus if able to do so).

In terms of real world products it would look like this:

[Motherboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N4LCX2D) > [4x SATA to SFF-8087](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013JP7YI8) > [SFF-8087 to SFF-8088 Adapter](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=609&area=en) > [External SFF-8088 Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013G4F3A8) > [External SAS Enclosure](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=483&area=en)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work as you wish. I believe you must be careful with (1) where you need SATA to SAS **reverse breakout cable** /not forward breakout one/.

The only problem I see you might have (happened to me with my enclosure) is if you use SAS drives in that enclosure /but you say that you will use 3 SATA drives/ so it should be ok.